# how to install conda with python 2.7 and with pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

trying to install conda with python 2.7 on macbook with M1 processor

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7
```

results in:

No match found for: 2.7.

** I tryied another way:

```
conda create --name py27
conda activate py27
python --version
```

Python 2.7.18

and then (since I need pip):

```
conda install pip=20
python --version
```

Python 3.10.1

Is there a way to solve this or does conda on arm only supports python 3?

Comment: Looks like you can try using `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` according to [this documentation page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python); does that change anything?

Comment: gives the same error:

'''
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=2.7
  - anaconda

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
'''

Comment: While the duplicate is about Python 3.7, the answer is the same: Python 2 sunset was prior to M1 chips, so no one is building it. If you need to run Python 2 on M1, then you must emulate.